# RestTemplate postForObject unable to map Custom class apart from String.class

Tags: java, spring-boot

I was trying to consume firebase Auth API using RestTemplate postForObject, but when I assign String.class as return type its working file but if I assign my custom class to handle the response its failed, although custom class property are same as the JSON return,

```
restTemplate.postForObject( uri, request, UserResponse.class);
```

```
public class UserResponse {

    private String kind;
    private String localId;
    private String email;
    private String displayName;
    private String idToken;
    private Boolean registered;

    public String getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    public void setKind(String kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
    }

    public String getLocalId() {
        return localId;
    }

    public void setLocalId(String localId) {
        this.localId = localId;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getIdToken() {
        return idToken;
    }

    public void setIdToken(String idToken) {
        this.idToken = idToken;
    }

    public Boolean getRegistered() {
        return registered;
    }

    public void setRegistered(Boolean registered) {
        this.registered = registered;
    }
}
```

Can any one where I am wrong;

Exceptions:

```
2020-04-09 16:06:06.980 ERROR 18200 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:787) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at aaa.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class aaa.model.UserResponse] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:123) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:741) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:674) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:418) ~[spring-web-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at aaa.config.Bootstrap.run(Bootstrap.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What exception you are getting can you add that in question

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner

Comment: can you add full exception log to question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `jackson` dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```